# Return value conversion from external Call

Tags: solidity

i have an external call inside a Contract function to another function.

Here is my code: Contract 1

```
function getContractForAddr(address ethAddress_) public payable returns (address){
   return adresses[ethAddress_].contractAddr;
}
```

Contract 2:

```
function testFunc(address to_){
   (bool success, bytes memory data) = mainContract.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("getContractForAddr(address)", to_));
}
```

I get a value inside the data field back and success is true but it is supposed to be a address.
How can i convert it to address? I already tried the [Seriality](https://github.com/pouladzade/Seriality) function.
I use Solidity > v0.5 ! 
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `address(data)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want the address cast it to an address with:

```
address addr = address(data)
```

Also, since you're in Solidity v0.5, if you want to call a transfer function on that address you'll need to cast it to a payable address.

```
address payable addr = address(uint160(data))
```